# Как запретить любые действия с tableView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitableview

Возникла надобность отключить любые возможные действия с tableView по типу `button.isEnabled = false`

Answer (score 2):

```
tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Так же можно в `storyboard` выбрать таблицу и поставить и убрать галочку `User Interaction Enabled`

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо!

Comment: @ИгорьИванов если ответ помог, поставьте галочку. :)